# Why does Cassius Green speak like this?

Tags: dialogue, sorry-to-bother-you

When Cassius Green talks to the Equisapiens after they help him break-out in *Sorry to Bother You*, he addresses them as such:

> We. Are. Honored. To. Be. In. Your. Presence

Why does he speak like this when in his previous encounter with the equisapiens, they were talking like normal humans and he heard them speak too? Why doesn't he talk normally to them instead of spacing out each word?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it comes down to Cassius being afraid of them still. He screamed and ran away when he originally saw them in Steve Lift's home. I think his nerves got the better of him and thus he spoke slowly as if he was still trying to figure out what to say as to not insult them.